# How to print </script> as text using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi i am trying to assing this  value to a variable in javascript but always get an error. I have no clue what is going on, my statement is something like:

```
var a = "</script>";
```

I tried everything but it does not work, what should i do instead??

Comment: Have your tried `var a = "<\/script>";`

Answer (score 4):

You need to hide that from the HTML parser:

```
var a = '</' + 'script>';
```

If you don't, then the surrounding HTML parser — which knows nothing at all about JavaScript syntax — thinks that that's the end of the script block. After it sees the opening tag for the block, it literally scans for `</script>` (ignoring case of course).

(*edit* — though basically right I think, my claim that browsers are searching strictly for `</script>` is probably somewhat overstated; I suspect that they look for anything that's recognizable as a closing tag. The basic point still stands of course.)

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question but if you are trying to output '' on the screen for the reader (human) to view, then you can use:

```
var a = "&lt;/script&gt;";
```

Note that this won't work for executable scripts however - it won't be interpreted as a html/script tag.